# Create resource file using C# Source Generators

Tags: c#, code-generation

I'm investigating using [C# Source Generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) for generating the boilerplate required for a specific program we write add-ins for. The boilerplate includes a C# class which I'm confident I can do with the generators but it also includes an embedded XML file which maps the functionality to static methods in the output dll.

Is there a way to output data that is not source code from the generator? In my specific case I need to create an embedded resource which contains an XML file.

I've looked through the [Source Generators Cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md) but haven't found anything similar to the scenario I pose above.

Comment: Nothing yet, looks like it's planned. [See here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49935)